# Does request paramters retain values through out lifecycle of a spring web flow

Tags: spring-webflow

At this link:http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?16393-Difference-between-Spring-MVC-Web-Framework-and-Web-Flow
it says: a webflow is "longer than a request but shorter than a session." Does it mean that request scoped parameters will retain their values so long as they are part of the same webflow without having to use a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, request scoped parameters will be lost when entering into a view state due to the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern used by Spring Web Flow. If you want to keep values during the whole flow you've got various possibilities:

- **Session scope**: The value will be there while the session is active.
- **Flow scope**: The value will be accessible during the whole flow
  execution.
- **Conversation scope**: The value will be accessible during
  the whole flow execution and from within its sub flows.

Also notice that these three scopes are stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

There are many scopes in Webflow which can be used for storing object. If you want object want to store for only request then there is `Request` Scope something like struts. Apart from there are `Session`, `Flow`, `Application`, `Flash` Scope also avaliable.

Multiple scopes gives you lot of flexibility. I guess this is what author of that post meant to say.

Comment: Further, Flow Scope is actually stored on the Session, but in a way that there can be more than one at the same time. So it still "uses" a session.